# How can you verify a multiple code point emoji is supported?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, emoji

For context, I'm trying to create a mapping from string code points to emojis and need to know if the system supports the emoji:

```
("1F9AE") -> ""
("1FAE0") -> "" (iOS 15.4+) / nil (if below 15.4, since it would show as "")
("1F415-200D-1F9BA") -> "‍"
("1F415-1F9BA") -> nil (since it would normally be "", which isn't a single emoji)
```

I've gotten this to work with the single code point case with:

```swift
func emoji(for codepoint: String) -> String? {
    guard let int = Int(codepoint, radix: 16),
        let scalar = UnicodeScalar(int),
        scalar.properties.isEmoji
    else { return nil }
    return String(scalar)
}
```

However, I can't figure out what the corresponding check for `isEmoji` with multiple code points would be.

```swift
// assume I had to make these scalars via a `String`
let scalars = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F415)!, UnicodeScalar(0x200D)!, UnicodeScalar(0x1F9BA)!]
let scalarView = String.UnicodeScalarView(scalars)
// How can I check that this `UnicodeScalarView` is for single, supported emoji, since I can't check `isEmoji`?
print(String(scalarView))
```

For example, `"1FAE0-1F3FD"` should be `nil`, since it's not a single emoji (`""`). However, in future versions, the melting face might work with skin variation, in which case it should return that single valid emoji.

Comment: Using `isEmoji` for single code points is problematic too. It returns true for things like digits.

Comment: @Sweeper I think that would be acceptable for my use case. It just needs to be a single character which can be displayed successfully (not the "" missing glyph character).

Comment: Then I think you're better off checking if the `AppleColorEmoji` font supports the glyph, and also that the scalars form a string of count 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Emoji 14.0's [data files](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/), an emoji is either a basic emoji, a keycap sequence, a flag, a modifier sequence, or a ZWJ sequence. In each of those cases, there will be at least one code point in the sequence for which `isEmoji` returns `true`, and the sequence will form a single glyph.

So, you *should* make a string out of the unicode scalars first:

```
let scalars = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F415)!, UnicodeScalar(0x200D)!, UnicodeScalar(0x1F9BA)!]
let scalarView = String.UnicodeScalarView(scalars)
let string = String(scalarView)
```

Then, you can check if it is a emoji like this:

```
CTLineGetGlyphCount(CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
    NSAttributedString(string: string)
)) == 1 && 
string.unicodeScalars.contains { $0.properties.isEmoji }
```

Alternatively, since you just want to check if the emoji can be displayed properly, you can use `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` to see if Apple Color Emoji supports the characters.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "AppleColorEmoji", size: 20)! as CTFont
var text = Array(string.utf16)
var glyphs = Array(repeating: 0 as CGGlyph, count: text.count)
let isEmoji = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &text, &glyphs, text.count) && 
    CTLineGetGlyphCount(CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
        NSAttributedString(string: string)
    )) == 1
```

Note that both of these methods will return false positives (non-emojis like ASCII letters being reported as emojis), but will not return false negatives.

Comment: This is great, thanks! However, both of these solutions don't catch the case "" ("\u{1FAE0}\u{1F3FD}"). That reports count == 1, even though it's shown as two.

Comment: @solidcell hmm, do note that though it looks like “two” emojis, it is still a single extended grapheme cluster. Anyway, I don’t have the iOS 15.4 SDK, so I can’t check this, but see if you can see something different in the `glyphs` array. I would imagine that you should be able to find 2 glyphs being drawn (2 non zero elements). How about checking that in addition to `string.count`?

Comment: True, it's still one cluster, but it's visibly two glyphs. Unfortunately, `string.count` still reports `1` when, for example, drawn as `` or `❗`. As for the glyphs array, the pattern returned is the same for something like  and , so it also doesn't seem to be the way to check.

Comment: How about `CTLineGetGlyphCount(CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: string)))`? That gotta be 2, right? It is 2 on iOS 15.0. Is it still 2 on iOS 15.4? @solidcell

Comment: That did it! Thanks for chipping away at this one with me Sweeper. It's tougher to check for this than I would have thought, that's for sure ;)

Comment: Funny, upon stress testing this, I found that this luckily catches cases which should be one glyph, but are two. Such as: ‍‍
I'm on macOS 12.3, so you might not see this, but the second glyph bleeds into the remaining text: ‍‍test test test

Comment: Although this looks fine on iOS 15.4 and still reports as being two glyphs. But better to over-guard than to let actual multi-glyphs through. So far I haven't found a way to catch this edge case.